# Profiling an executable with cabal

Tags: haskell, cabal-install

After some of the recent-ish changes to cabal, I am totally confused as to how to profile an executable. In `~/.cabal/config`, I have profiling enabled:

```
amy@wombat$ grep prof ~/.cabal/config
library-profiling: True
executable-profiling: True
```

But if I try to run my executable with profiling, I get...

```
amy@wombat$ cabal run realtra-benchmark +RTS -p
cabal: the flag -p requires the program to be built with -prof
cabal: 
cabal: Usage: <prog> <args> [+RTS <rtsopts> | -RTS <args>] ... --RTS <args>
<snip>
```

I get the same response if I try to bypass cabal: `./dist/dist-sandbox-c8599c64/build/realtra-benchmark/realtra-benchmark +RTS -p`.

Of course, adding the `-prof` flag to `GHC-Options:` in my cabal file won't work:

```
amy@wombat$ cabal build --ghc-options=-Werror && cabal test && cabal install
./realtra.cabal has been changed. Re-configuring with most recently used
options. If this fails, please run configure manually.
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring creatur-realtra-1.0.8...
Warning: 'ghc-options: -prof' is not necessary and will lead to problems when
used on a library. Use the configure flag --enable-library-profiling and/or
--enable-executable-profiling.
```

I figure I shouldn't have to add those flags since they're in my config file, but just in case, I try it:

```
amy@wombat$ cabal configure --enable-executable-profiling --enable-library-profiling
Resolving dependencies...
Configuring creatur-realtra-1.0.8...
amy@wombat$ cabal build --ghc-options=-Werror && cabal test && cabal install
<snip>
amy@wombat$ cabal run realtra-benchmark +RTS -p
cabal: the flag -p requires the program to be built with -prof
cabal: 
cabal: Usage: <prog> <args> [+RTS <rtsopts> | -RTS <args>] ... --RTS <args>
<snip>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try this:`cabal run realtra-benchmark +RTS -p -RTS`

Comment: The `-RTS` flag is only needed when you're following with non-runtime flags. But just to make sure, I tried it just now with `-RTS` at the end, and got the same error.

Comment: Try `cabal run realtra-benchmark -- +RTS -p`. My guess is that `+RTS` gets interpreted as argument to the `cabal` executable itself.

Comment: Or maybe `cabal run realtra-benchmark +RTS --RTS -- +RTS -p`.

Comment: @Mikhail, both of your suggestions worked. If you want to add this as an answer, I'll accept it. I suspect this info will help others as well, because I googled (or rather, DuckDuckGo'd) extensively for an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that the `+RTS -p` bit gets interpreted as arguments to the `cabal` executable itself. To forward these arguments to the `realtra-benchmark` executable, use `cabal run realtra-benchmark -- +RTS -p`. In general, you should always put a double dash before the arguments that you want to be forwarded when you're using `cabal run` (at least until [this issue](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1119) is fixed).